# Suppress warnings for variables defined at runtime in Webstorm/IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, meteor, webstorm

Jetbrains IDEs like Webstorm have a code inspector which warns you when you use an unresolved variable.

The Meteor framework has a "Meteor.settings" object which is available at runtime. The framework looks at environment variables and/or loads a JSON file with your settings, and it makes that data available to the application.

Recent versions of Jetbrains IDEs claim support for Meteor. Despite that, my IDE doesn't understand all of the above, and complains about an unresolved variable anywhere in my code where I've used a Meteor.settings.foo variable.

What's the best way to suppress that warning?

Comment: Do you keep the settings file (json) in your project root?

Comment: I typically put the meteor stuff in a src/ directory, and config files in a config/ directory. Meteor likes to automatically include all the files it finds in the directory, and sometimes I find that's a problem, so I've taken to putting all the meteor things in their own directory.

Comment: Is there a settings.json convention I'm unaware of for development settings or for documenting the general expected structure of the settings file that will get used at runtime?

Comment: What exactly does the IDE complain about? I, too, am using Webstorm and a settings.json which is a simple json key value pair. BTW, take a look at https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-organizing-environment-variables-and-settings for some productivity tips on that matter

Comment: That's a great resource, agreed. I get this: " Problem synopsis Unresolved variable public at line 5 " when I ask it inspect the code in my project. Where line 5 in my code is a line where I am referencing one of the public settings in my file.  Similar story for private settings.

Comment: I see your problem now, I've posted an answer which I think should work.

Comment: if the actual data is only known at runtime, WebStorm has no ways to resolve json objects during static analysis - thus the 'unresolved variable' errors. Please see http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5504337#5504337 for possible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If webstorm cannot resolve that variable, you can alternatively fake an initialization by assigning it to itself in your source.

You can do this somewhere in your `client/lib` folder within a `Meteor.startup()` block.

```
public = public || {};
```

Or if it complains about its nested properties, you can do the same with that as well:

```
public = public || { prop1:{}, prop2: {} };
```

This way, webstorm will just think it is an empty object but at run time, since it is already initialized, you'll be able to use the actual value.

I know this is a hack, but it will save you the troubles with IDE code inspection.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide an error by adding a `@namespace` annotation, like this:

```
/** @namespace Meteor.settings */
Meteor.settings
```

From this moment on IntelliJ will no longer notices like:

> Unresolved variable settings at line XXX

Remember, that it's just a workaround for a line, where you see a notice. It'll not fix the root of a problem.